# update hashtable in enumerator and have it recognize that add?

Tags: powershell

What is the best way to handle doing an add to a hashtable inside of enumeration of that hashtable so that it includes that added item in the enumeration?

I havo something lke:
        foreach ($key in $groups.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object Name -descending) {
               if (something) {
                   groups.add("test","test2")
               }
        }

I want it to use the new added item in the enumeration instead of calling the function that has this in it over and over, which was killing my memory resources and cuasing issues with affecting what was getting written out to export-csv call.

Answer (score 0):

I think powershell throws an error when you update a hash you are walking with foreach.

Write your hash's keys into an array:

```
$stack = @($groups.keys)
```

Then "shift" a key off that list to work it:

```
while ($stack) {
  $item,$stack = $stack
  DoStuffHere()
}
```

And finally, in DoStuffHere, you'll need to add an item to the HASH **and** push the new key onto the stack so it gets worked.

```
 $groups.add($newkey,$newval)
 $stack = $stack,$newkey
```

This way, you have no worries about powershell's automatic behavior not working the way you want.

Comment: I must be doing this wrong.  I tried: $stack = $groups.key
 while ($stack) {
  $group,$stack = $stack
  $group = $key.Value
  Write-Output "Group off stack : $($group)"  but $group is not set to anything.

Comment: I used $key still when trying your suggestion, and I think you have to use $stack = $groups.keys instead of $groups.key.  However, after doing this $group from $group,$stack = $stack was equal to all the groups instead of just popping one off for some reason.

Comment: I changed the $stack = $groups.key to $stack = @($groups.keys) and that seems to help.

Comment: I would love for his to work, but it is not yet.  I have in the loop a point where it adds a new key to the stack via $stack += $newkey, but when it gets up to the top of the loop, it shows what it popped off as $null or empty.  It is like it added when I did the $stack += $newkey something, but not $newkey's real value.  I did verify that $newkey is set with a value.

Comment: Interesting.  If I watch the $stack, I see things getting popped off when I run $key,$stack = $stack.  It shows $key with one of the keys as expected.  However, if I do the $stack  += $newkey, the next $key that is popped off is the entire content of the $stack--in that, I see with stack a,b,c key = a, then key = b, key=c, and then I add to the stack 'd' and then key = a b c d.

Comment: Sigh, okay what I had to do was instead of $stack += $newkey, I had to do $stack = $stack,$newkey.

Comment: Powershell is soooo weird. I'll update the answer to match your new tweak.